# Why is sizeof giving incorrect number of bytes in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

I am trying to get size of an array in C++ to be used for stuff later on. Why does this yield 16?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[4];
    cout << sizeof(a) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Should it not give 20? Because there are basically 20 bytes in this array from a[0] through a[4]? Size of an element can be verified by getting -

```
sizeof(a[0])
```

Now this is 4. 16/4 = 4, which means there are 4 blocks of 4 bytes, when there actually should be 5. Why is that?

P.S. My main confusion stemmed from getting sizeof(a[4]) - which is 4. Since it was giving an output 4 - I thought it was part of the array.

Comment: Why do you think there are 5 blocks?  `int a[4];` says make an array of 4 blocks.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: When you declare an array with n-elements (e.g. `int a[4];` where `n=4`), the valid indexes are from `0 -> (n-1)`. There is no `a[n]` (e.g. `a[4]`) element.

Comment: *Why is sizeof giving incorrect number of bytes in C++?* -- That would be major news if a computer language couldn't get its own rules correct.  Of course `sizeof` is returning the correct number, otherwise C++ programmers would be in big trouble.

Comment: Recommendation: try to avoid arrays. They are really simple and really stupid. You have to jump though hoops to get information out of them like you did to get the size of 4 elements. Arrays always pass by reference, so you can't do that trick in a function because you'll get the size of the pointer to the array that the function sees. You can't return an array from a function because it is returned by reference and goes out of scope leaving you with a pointer to invalid memory. You'll find `std::array`, a smart wrapper around the array to me more useful.

Comment: Note: you may also be interested in [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Comment: Fun fact: `"hola"` is an array of 5 chars. It won't fit into `char hello[4] = "hola";`, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @rustyx you may want to explain why it is 5 bytes due to the terminating null byte of a string literal. I don't think that will be obvious to OP.

Comment: This reminds me of the old BASIC days, where `DIM A(10)` would actually create an array of 11 elements, indexed from 0 thru 10.  C++ does *not* behave that way.

Answer (score 13):

If you declare array `a[4]`, it means it has **4** elements.
The only valid indicies are `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and `a[3]`.

Accessing `a[4]` is invalid.
I don't know why you think `a[4`] would have 5 elements in it.

This array has 4 elements, and its size is:

```
4-elements * 4-bytes = 16 bytes.
```

Comment: I was just confused about why then when I did executed sizeof(a[4]), the output is 4. Why exactly is that? Interestingly - for sizeof([a[534]) - I get the same output. Which is why I was confused in the first place.

Comment: `a` is an array of integers... ANY `int` in that array (even at invalid indicies) has type `int`, and size 4.   Try `sizeof(a[-4])`, and you'll see even negative indicies are possible.

Comment: Interestingly - sizeof(a[-3/2]) also gives 4. That is just baffling.

Comment: No, it is not baffling.   `-3/2 == -1`. (If you think it is `-1.5`, you are very wrong). `a[-1]` is a pretty basic case.  No mystery there.

Answer (score 2):

The output is not wrong. When you declare an array `int a[4]`, it has 4 blocks of data `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]` and `a[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

When doing `int a[4];` you are declaring an array of `4` integers. Therefore the size of the whole vector is 4 times the size of one `int` (and if the `int` happens to be 4 bytes, then the product is 16 bytes).

C/C++ (and many other languages) use a zero-based indexing. Which means that the elements of the array defined above are numbered from `0` to `3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[4];
```

has four elements: `a[0]`,`a[1]`,`a[2]` and `a[3]`.